# how to create a temporary file in /tmp from a servlet?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, ubuntu-12.04, temporary-files

I am using `File.createTempFile` from within a Servlet (the `createTempFile` version with only prefix and suffix but without a `File` argument).

According to the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) this should create a file in the system's default temporary directory (in my case `/tmp`). Instead, the file gets created in `/tmp/tomcat7-tomcat7-tmp/`.

Why the strange temporary file location and how can I change it to the "normal" temporary file location for my system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java uses system property `java.io.tmpdir` to get current temporary directory. As far as I remember one of the scripts that run tomcat sets this variable to what you mentioned. If it is imprtant for you you should re-write this variable. Try to grep tomcat scripts, find this place and override it. Probably you can  set `JAVA_OPTS=$JAVA_OPTS java.io.tmpdir=/tmp` or something like this when running tomcat. (Obviously the syntax depends on your OS).